# Google Chrome limits upload speed to 10mbits when minimized (testet on Win10 and Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop)

Tags: google-chrome, upload, limit, minimized

Has anyone an explanation for the following behaviour:

When I upload something with chrome through small xhr requests everything works fine. But when I minimize Chrome the upload drops[The networkgraph shows the drop when chrome gets minimized and how it returns to normal speed when maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9y53.png) to pretty much exactly 10mbits. I tried this on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop.
The download speed is not affected. There is no change if chrome is minimized or not.
The same behaviour seems to be with Firefox too.

I already did quite an extensive search, but to no avail, inkluding searching for "chrome bandwith limit while minimized" and the like did not bring up any answer. I even asked ChatGPT :)

Further I checked with chrome://discards and disabled "Auto Discardable" but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to answer my own question. After some research I think the reason are the small xhr requests. Webbrowsers throttle javascript execution when in the background. And thus the callback for the xhr requests are presumably also throttled which leads to the 10MBit/s upper limit on transfer. Downloads do not get throttled when in the background, which kind of supports my theory.